# Why did SQL syntax change after restoring local Postgres onto AWS RDS?

Tags: postgresql, sequelize.js, amazon-rds, dbeaver

## Problem

A simple 2x2 table of data explains my problem. Both databases can be made to work, but they behave differently and I need them to be the same.

```
 PostreSQL Query           |  Local DB  |  Amazon-RDS                             |
 --------------------------+------------+-----------------------------------------+
 SELECT * from mydb.users; |  Success   |  Success                                |
 --------------------------+------------+-----------------------------------------+
 SELECT * from users;      |  Success   |  ERROR: relation "users" does not exist |
 ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

## Details

1. The databases should be identical.  Amazon-RDS is literally `pg_restore`'d from a `pg_dump` of the local database.  Exact commands:

   ```sh
   $ pg_dump --format=c ---no-privileges --no-owner --verbose \
            --host=localhost --port=5432 --username=gary mydb;

   $ pg_restore --no-owner --no-tablespaces --dbname=mydb --verbose \
      --host=127.0.0.1 --port=47737 \ #ssh tunnel
      --username=XXXXXX --format=c
   ```
2. The problem is not with the data dump itself. I've wiped the local database, restored it from the dump, and it still behaves the way it's supposed to.
3. The problem doesn't just manifest not just with my raw SQL queries, there's a sizable Node/Express app that is supposed to front-end the database. It generates queries without the database prefix in front of the tables too. The app uses Sequelize for an ORM and has been running with MySQL on Amazon-RDS in
   production for years. The issue I'm seeing now has only appeared while migrating from MySQL to PostgreSQL.
4. I have no experience with Postgres.
5. I don't think it should matter, but in full disclosure, I'm using DBeaver to handle all my database connections, and do the db dump and restore.

## Questions

1. Why does one database successfully infer the database from the name of the table alone, and not the other cannot?
2. Is there a configuration setting somewhere to make them both work?  `mydb` is the only database in the RDS instance.

Comment: I think there might be a selection of database/schema when you connect to the db. It will be the default and you don't need to specify for that database/schema, in general.

Comment: `mydb` is not a database, it's a schema. And it appears that it is not [in the `search_path`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/ddl-schemas.html#DDL-SCHEMAS-PATH) on RDS, which is configured either in the cluster settings, the settings of your database, the settings of your (login) user, or locally on the DBeaver connection.

Comment: Yes @Bergi, that's exactly the detail I was missing. Post your response as an answer instead of a comment and I'll mark it as the solution.   Thanks.

Comment: @GaryKumfert Just curious, where was it configured and how was it different?

Comment: On RDS, `search_path == "$user",public` by default.  I can change it directly  (`SET search_path TO public,mydb`) to confirm the fix, but it doesn't persist beyond the editor's session. My options for fixing this permanently seem to be one of the following: (1) make  a custom "Parameter Group" that sets `search_path` and configure the database with that, (2) put all the tables in the public schema so I don't have to worry about custom configurations (i.e. `ALTER TABLE users SET SCHEMA public`), or (3) rename the database admin as  `mydb` -- which should map to `"$user" in the search path.

Comment: FWIW: I'm going with option #2 above.  The source of the schema/database confusion is `pgloader` conversion from MySQL to PostgreSQL.  e.g. https://github.com/dimitri/pgloader/issues/645

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`mydb` is not a database, it's a schema. And it appears that it is not [in the schema `search_path`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/ddl-schemas.html#DDL-SCHEMAS-PATH) on RDS.

It could be configured in the cluster settings, the settings of your database, the settings of your (login) user, or locally on the DBeaver connection.